# Docker container stops without any errors while runnning sbt/play application

Tags: docker, playframework, sbt

I'm running into an issue where my docker container will exit with exit code `137` after ~a day of running.  The logs for the container contains no information indicating that an error code has occurred.  Additionally, attempts to restart the container returns an error that the PID already exists for the application.

The container is built using the sbt docker plugin, `sbt docker:publishLocal` and is then run using 
`docker run --name=the_app --net=the_app_nw -d  the_app:1.0-SNAPSHOT`.

I'm also running 3 other docker containers which all together do use 90% of the available memory, but its only ever that particular container which exits.

Looking for any advice on to where to look next.

Comment: Please provide the output of `docker inspect the_app` from the failed container, and show the command and output of the restart that gives you an error. The output of `docker ps -a` while the container is down may also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error code 137 (128+9) means that it was killed (like `kill -9 yourApp`) by something. That something can be a lot of things (maybe it was killed because was using too much resources by docker or something else, maybe it got out of memory, etc)

Regarding the pid problem, you can add to your `build.sbt` this

```
javaOptions in Universal ++= Seq(
  "-Dpidfile.path=/dev/null"
)
```

Basically this should instruct Play to not create a `RUNNING_PID` file. If it does not work you can try to pass that option directly in Docker using the `JAVA_OPTS` env variable.